# Making a vector out of excel columns using python

Tags: excel, pandas, xlrd

everyone...
I just started on python a couple of days ago because I require to handle some excel data in order to automatically update the data of certain cells from one file into another.

However, I'm kind of stuck since I have barely programmed before, and it's my first time using python as well, but my job required me to find a solution and I'm trying to make it work even though it's not my field of expertise.

I used the "xlrd library", imported my file and managed to print the columns I'm needing... However, I can't find a way to put those columns into a matrix in order to handle the data like this:

Matrix =[DataColumnA     DataColumnG  DataColumnH] in the size [nrows x 3]

As for now, I have 3 different outputs for the 3 different columns I need, but I'm trying to join them together into one big matrix.

So far my code looks like this:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("190219_serviciosWRAmanualV5.xls");
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("ServiciosDWDM");

workbook2 = xlrd.open_workbook("Potencia2.xlsx");
worksheet2 = workbook2.sheet_by_name("Hoja1");

filas = worksheet.nrows
filas2 = worksheet2.nrows
columnas = worksheet.ncols


for row in range (2, filas):
    Equipo_A = worksheet.cell(row,12).value
    Client_A = worksheet.cell(row,13).value
    Line_A = worksheet.cell(row, 14).value
    print (Equipo_A, Line_A, Client_A)
```

So I have only gotten, as mentioned above, the data in the columns which is what I'm printing which you can see.

What I'm trying to do, or the main thing I need to do is to read the cell of the first row in Column A and look for it in the other excel file... if the names match, I would have to validate that for the same row (in file 1) the data in both the ColumnG and ColumnH is the same as the data in the second file.
If they match I would have to update Column J in the first file with the data from the second file.

My other approach is to retrieve the value of the cell in ColumnA and look for it in the column A of the second file, then I would make an if conditional to see if ColumnsG and H are equal to Column C of 2nd file and so on...
The thing here is, I have no idea how to pin point the position of the cell and extract the data to make the conditional for this second approach.

I'm not sure if by making that matrix my approach is okay or if the second way is better, so any suggestion would be absolutely appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just checking. You want to take Book1.ColumnA values and look for them in Bk2.Column A ?  If they match the Bk1.ColumnG and Bk1.ColumnH should match Bk2.ColumnG and Bk2.ColumnH - for their respective rows ?  If they match then Bk1.ColumnJ set = to Bk2.ColumnJ ...... Is that about right ?

Comment: My 2nd query, sounds like you are saying Bk1.ColG and Bk1.ColH = Bk2.ColC .... which suggests Bk1.ColG = Bk1.ColH ... I;m not entirely clear

Comment: Yes, indeed.
I'm trying to get the first name on Book.1 ColumnA and look for it in Book2.ColumnA. I'm going to get multiple matches, so then the way I need to validate is the information of Book1.ColumnG (for the same row) and Book1.ColumnH should match the information on Book2.ColumnC and Book2.ColumnD, if so... then I would have to get the information on the cell for Book2.ColumnE and write it on Book1.ColumnJ. I have a huge Book1 of around 1553 rows and Book2 has a different format, of around 4388 rows. I'm worried, If I code something wrong, I would "set" the wrong data for a certain row.